# ConnectHardwareKeyboard property on browserstack/lambdatest real devices for iOS input issue

Tags: ios, node.js, typescript, appium, browserstack

I have encountered issue where iOS input fields cannot be interacted with and I cannot find proper solution, because I am using real devices rather than simulator on mac (I am working on windows).

So after a bit investigation I narrowed it to ConnectHardwareKeyboard property, which doesn't allow software keyboard to be opened and inputs sent. However I have no control in capabilities over this property as I use real devices from browserstack/lambdatest.

Was an actual fix introduced for this issue or just work arounds for simulators?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your use case here?

Also, please raise a support ticket by sending an email to support@browserstack.com or via this link, https://www.browserstack.com/contact#technical-support.

Comment: @HomeLander it's not related to browserstack itself, it's related to 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327556/ios-simulator-disable-connect-hardware-keyboard-programmatically

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/11007

additionally support ticket was sent to browserstack, but they haven't responded if it's possible to affect property somehow.